# Woocommerce: Get all orders for a product

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In the Woocommerce API I see a method wc_get_orders

[WooCommerce Order Functions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_order.html#88-101%20%22%22)

In the mentioned args I do not see an argument in which I could provide a product ID or Object to limit order results only for that specific product.

Is there a way I could filter orders only for specific products?

I need to use this method since some arguments are necessary

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Edited**
This function doesn't exist, but it can be built. So the function below will return an array of all orders IDs for a given product ID, making the right SQL query:

```
/**
 * Get All orders IDs for a given product ID.
 *
 * @param  integer  $product_id (required)
 * @param  array    $order_status (optional) Default is 'wc-completed'
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_orders_ids_by_product_id( $product_id, $order_status = array( 'wc-completed' ) ){
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT order_items.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
    ");

    return $results;
}
```

**USAGE 1** (for a given product ID **`37`** and default Completed orders status):

```
$orders_ids = get_orders_ids_by_product_id( 37 );

// The output (for testing)
print_r( $orders_ids );
```

**USAGE 2** (for a given product ID **`37`** and **some defined orders statuses**):

```
// Set the orders statuses
$statuses = array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' );

$orders_ids = get_orders_ids_by_product_id( 37, $statuses );

// The output (for testing)
print_r( $orders_ids );
```

**USAGE 3** (for a given product ID **`37`** and **some defined orders statuses AND then obtain the order object via the order id**):

```
// Set the orders statuses
$statuses = array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' );

$orders_ids = get_orders_ids_by_product_id( 37, $statuses );

// The output (for testing)
print_r( $orders_ids );

// Loop through
foreach ( $orders_ids as $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {     
        echo $order->get_status() . '<br>'; // The order status
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Hello LoicTheAztec, how do I modifiy the sql if I have more than one meta key value. Example like colors > red? Thanks!

Comment: @somtam You need to add one more: `LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta2 ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta2.order_item_id`… then you will be able to use a new `order_item_meta2.meta_key` or/and `order_item_meta2.meta_value`…

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! One more thing. Usually with get_col() I escape the sql, like $results = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($sql,$id));. Do I have to do that or get_col escape by itself? thanks.

Comment: @somtam prepare() method allow more security to avoid SQL injections in some cases. In this question case I don't need it. It's up to you to see if you really need that.

Comment: Why LEFT JOINs? Shouldn't those be INNER JOINs? Also, can you update your answer and use wpdb::prepare()? SQL injection is no joke, let's not raise another generation of poor WP devs.

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't entirely future-proof. Especially since WooCommerce 8 will start moving to [HPOS tables](https://woocommerce.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/), it's best to use the WooCommerce API's. Unfortunately, I haven't yet found a way to do what you want with their API, so you may have to continue with custom SQL. Just be aware of DB schema changes.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is an old answer, when WooCommerce version was between 3 and 4. For sure, things have already changed and will change even more, very soon.

Answer (score 5):

So I wanted to fetch orders specific to a product and a person. I used the solution provided by @LoicTheActec with the wc_get_orders woocommerce method to get the result I want.

Here are the functions:

```
    /**
 * Get All orders IDs for a given product ID.
 *
 * @param  integer  $product_id (required)
 * @param  array    $order_status (optional) Default is 'wc-completed'
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function get_orders_ids_by_product_id( $product_id, $order_status = array( 'wc-completed' ) ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT order_items.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
    ");

    return $results;
}
```

To filter out the results I want. Since the method does not provide an include argument I had to grab all the orders and then remove the order for the given product id and exclude all the remaining from wc_get_orders:

```
    /**
 * Check if current user has more than 3 orders
 *
 * @return void
 * @author 
 **/
public function woocommerce_check_order_count($product_id, $customer_email)
{   


    $statuses = array(  'wc-processing' );

    $orders_ids_for_product = $this->get_orders_ids_by_product_id( $product_id, $statuses );


    // Get All Orders
    $allorders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'status'      => 'processing',
        'type'        => 'shop_order',
        'email'       => '',
        'limit'       => -1,
        'return'      => 'ids',
    ) );

    // Remove the $orders_ids_for_product array from the $allorders array
    $orderstoexclude = array_diff($allorders, $orders_ids_for_product);

    $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'status'      => 'processing',
        'type'        => 'shop_order',
        'customer'    => $customer_email,
        'email'       => '',
        'limit'       => 3,
        'exclude'     => $orderstoexclude,
        'return'      => 'ids',
    ) );

    return $orders;

}
```