# WooCommerce - number of returns for a specific product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to count % of returns for specific product im my WooCommerce store.

Lets say I have `$product` with ID = 93.

I can get number of total sales for this product like that:
`$product->get_total_sales()`

How can I get number of total returns for that specific product?

I tried to search WooCommerce docs, but couldn't find function like that. Maybe I can get all orders that have this product returned, but thats seems like a too much steps.

Comment: I mean what is total number of returns for product with ID=93? 
For example: Customers bought 100 times this product and returned 10 times. I want to get number of returned products (which is 10).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848249/woocommerce-get-all-orders-for-a-product . This is not perfect solution because you cant tell what is refunded from order itself as real product you have notes to describe what its refunded.